# What is the name of the song that plays during the cutscene where Sora is on The Grid and Xemnas describes the digital nature of The Grid?

Tags: game-music-identification, kingdom-hearts-dream-drop-distance

There is a song in *Kingdom Hearts 3D* that plays during cutscenes, usually when one of the villains is explaining a [mind screw](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MindScrew) concept to one of the protagonists. Particularly you can hear it at [this point in the game](https://web.archive.org/web/20130622035745/http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rf-DRCBVeXs) (at the 1:41:43 part of the video) where Sora is on The Grid and Xemnas describes the digital nature of The Grid, and that Ansem the Wise used a copy of its data for his operating system at the Radiant Garden. I can't find it anywhere in the soundtrack on youtube, and my google search has been turning up blank as well. Can anyone name this song?

Comment: I don't mind downvotes, but is there something wrong with my question? It's been a while since I've posted here so I realize I may not be entirely in tune with what's acceptable and what's not here.

Comment: Your question seems tangentially adequate to the definition of game identification and soundtrack stuff is usually okay here. I think the bigger issue is that a) you tagged wrong, but Fluttershy fixed that, and b) have a somewhat unhelpful question title - if anyone were to search for the same information on google, your question title and body might not be sufficient to have it pull up as a result. Perhaps a more accurate title like "what is the name of the song that plays when (insert specific instance without generalizing)"

Comment: @skovacs1 I considered that, but I was concerned that that would inadvertently put a spoiler in the title. Is there any rule regarding spoilers in the title? If not, I'll edit to make it more descriptive.

Comment: The title is better, but even in the description, you'd be fine putting that level of spoiler. Like "during the scene in Tron where you meet..." or "during the scene at the end of..." or some other scene that is maybe less spoiler-ish so long as it is clearly and uniquely identified. The game's been out a good while so that level of spoiler is pretty benign. If you feel it's too much of a spoiler, in the description, you can always use the blockquote-style spoiler markup: >! this is an example spoiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample starts about 40 seconds in and is at a low volume, but the song is [*The Nightmare*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etRi1tQjk-E). It's song number 3 on disk 2 of the soundtrack.

Comment: Ah that explains why I couldn't find it. Thanks much!